# Java read socket Tcp faster

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I run this code and it's OK, but I got an output about every 5 or more secs (like it's blocked), while it should be many times per second; the size of the line (dati) is variable.

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5333); 
PrintStream wr = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
wr.println("sub"); 
InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir); 
String dati;
while ((dati = br.readLine()) != null){  
    System.out.println(dati); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It *is* blocked. Waiting for data from the sender. You can't read any faster than the sender is sending.

Comment: I wonder what happens if no line terminator is sent and, eventually, some internal buffer fills up?